# How to find vector who's ith index is the average of another vector up to index i

Tags: r, vector, average

Suppose I have a list c(1,2,3,4,5)
I want to find the list c(1,1.5,2,2.5,3). basically, a list who's ith index is the average of another vector's element from 1:i.

Is there any nice ways to find this? either a package or map function?

Comment: what is the point of seq_along(c(1,2,3,4,5)? Isn't it just the same as 1:length(c(1,2,3,4,5))? What can seq_along(x) do that 1:x can't?

Comment: FYI `c(1, 2, 3)` is a vector. A list is `list(1, 2, 3)`